# adding Belongs to without "nil" in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Hi I am creating one application there I have user table and some tables that belongs to user says account,purchase like that.I have created some users and testing. Now I need to add another table that also belongs to user says products , I have added the product table. Now whenever I call user.product.some_variable it says nil because there is no data in its now what i am doing is deleting all test users and recreate them, is there any way to avoid this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it many ways. Checkout the followings:

```
#1
user.product.try(:some_methods) 
#2
user.product.some_method if user.product.present?
```

Comment: You can add one more way using `rescue nil`

Comment: Where should you place rescue in your view?

Comment: is this a question related to the actual question? why view is important here?

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
user.product.try(:some_variable) if user.product.present?
```

Comment: when you come to user.product.try(:some_method) you won't need to check if user.product.present? Solution can be done in many ways.

Comment: If we won't check `user.product.present` then it may give exception, if its not present.

Comment: no. because using try on nil doesn't return exception. `nil.try(:ok) => nil`
so if user.product is nil then using try on nil won't raise exception. try it on rails console.

Comment: @Rubyrider Thanks .. I didn't knew that.